# How to delete a value from a multi-value entity reference field with EntityMetadataWrapper

Tags: 7, entities

I have multiple values in an entity reference field.  I want to delete one of those values, but ::clear doesn't seem to work.  I basically just want to do an unset, like:

```
$wrapper->field_entityrefs[3]->delete();
```

or something clean like that.  What is the best way?

Comment: Not tried it, but how about just `unset($wrapper->field_entityrefs[3])`?

Comment: I've confirmed the `unset($wrapper->field_entityrefs[3])` approach works, just follow it with a `$wrapper->save()` call.

Comment: tyler.frankenstein 's  solution worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
$wrapper->field_entityrefs[3]->set();
```

Also, to test if the field is there in the first place:

```
$wrapper->__isset('field_entityrefs');
```

I'm now finding myself calling __isset() on all wrapper fields.

Comment: I get warnings, such as Missing argument 1 for EntityDrupalWrapper::set()